# NiFi load balancing strategy for higher throughput and lower IO

Tags: apache-nifi

For a dataflow running on a clustered NiFi instance, when configuring connections between processors, I have a two choices.

Assuming three processors A,B,C

Option 1:

```
A -> Round Robin  -> B -> Round Robin -> C
```

OR

Option 2:

```
A -> Round Robin  -> B  -> C
```

Considering that my job has a mix of small (few KB) and large (few MB) flow files, Would it be better to go with option 2? Since in Option 2 we are reducing the network IO by not distributing the flow files again among nodes. Or Option 1, where the load is evening distributing among nodes for all three processors.

At present, I can measure throughput but don't have a way to measure IO, hence the question.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It mainly depends of the processors used.

If your processors B is 1:1, ie: for a dataflow you have more or less same output size and same number of flowfile, you should go for option 2

```
A -> Round Robin  -> B  -> C
```

However, if your processor is 1:X and it depend on the flowfile ( for exemple splitting the flowfile content and add informations), you can except a machine to have much more work to do than other so a round robin can be considered with option 1 :

```
A -> Round Robin  -> B -> Round Robin -> C
```